# ValueError: math domain error when length is 4 and height is 2

Tags: python, mathematics

Breaking my head over this.

I am getting the ValueError: math domain error when running this script.
But only when lenght1=4 and height1=2
change 1 of the numbers and the script runs just fine.

When the value of lenght is 3.99 and lower or 4.01 and higher // height is 1.99 and lower or 2.01 and higher the error does not show.

When running the script the sliders in the operator menu can be used to adjust the values.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix
import math
from math import asin, degrees
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper

from bpy.props import (
    IntProperty,
    BoolProperty,
    FloatProperty,
)


class MESH_OT_primitive_arc(AddObjectHelper, bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add a simple arc mesh"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.primitive_arc"
    bl_label = "Add Circular Arc"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    length1: FloatProperty(
        name="length",
        description="Chord Length",
        min=0.01,
        max=100.0,
        default=4,
        unit='LENGTH',
    )
    height1: FloatProperty(
        name="Height",
        description="Arc Height",
        min=0.01,
        max=100.0,
        unit='LENGTH',
        default=2,
    )
    segments: IntProperty(
        name="Arc Segments",
        description="Number of Segments",
        min=1,
        default=8,
    )
    wallt: FloatProperty(
        name="Height",
        description="Arc Height",
        min=0.01,
        max=100.0,
        unit='LENGTH',
        default=0.2,
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        '''Generic Draw'''
        layout = self.layout
        # annnotated on this class
        for prop in self.__class__.__annotations__.keys():
            layout.prop(self, prop)
        # annotated on AddObjectHelper
        for prop in AddObjectHelper.__annotations__.keys():
            layout.prop(self, prop)


    def execute(self, context):

        bm = bmesh.new()




        h1 = (self.height1 - self.wallt)
        print(h1)
        if h1 <= 0 :
           h1 = 0.001
        a1 = ((self.length1 / 2) - self.wallt)
        r1 = (a1 * a1 + h1 * h1) / (2 * h1)
        print(r1)
#        if abs(a1 / r1) > 1:
            # math domain error on arcsin
#            return {'CANCELLED'}
        angle1 = 2 * asin(a1 / r1)
        #print(math.degrees(angle1))
        
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("Arc1")

        v1 = bm.verts.new((0, r1, 0))
        bmesh.ops.rotate(
            bm, verts=[v1], matrix=Matrix.Rotation(angle1 / 2, 3, 'Z'))

        bmesh.ops.spin(
            bm,
            geom=[v1],
            axis=(0, 0, 1),
            steps=self.segments,
            angle=-angle1,
        )

        for v1 in bm.verts[:]:
            v1.co.y -= r1 - h1
            #print(v1.co.y)
            v1.select = True


        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
        #mesh.update()

        # add the mesh as an object into the scene with this utility module
        from bpy_extras import object_utils
        object_utils.object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(MESH_OT_primitive_arc.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_primitive_arc)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_primitive_arc)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # Auto-run script comment out to disable auto run
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_arc()
```

Answer (score 1):

$arcsin(x)$ is only valid for $-1 \le x \le 1$. Any value outside of this range will generate a *domain error*, as you've indicated in the commented out test in your script

```
#        if abs(a1 / r1) > 1:
#            math domain error on arcsin
#            return {'CANCELLED'}
```

The values you have specified for `length1` and `height1` *should* produce a value of exactly 1 for `a1 / r1` but because of the way the equations are calculated, they produce the value `1.0000000000000002`, causing the domain error.

`h1` and `r1` should both have the exact value `1.8`, but the rounding error gives `h1 = 1.7999999970197678` and `r1 = 1.7999999970197675` leading to the domain error.

A workaround would be to replace your if statement with something like your test for `h1`:

```
x = a1 / r1
if x > 1.0:
    x = 1.0
elif x < -1.0
    x = -1.0
```